# writing Keysight Binary Arbitrary (.barb) waveforms

Tags: signal, waveform, function-generator

Keysight 33600 waveform generators load waveforms in either .arb (ASCII) or .barb (binary) formats. For large waveforms with more than ~10M samples .barb load much faster.

How can I create .barb files from my computer? (excluding the Keysight Benchlink software).
I am looking something similar to [this Tektronix .tfw creating code](https://forum.tek.com/viewtopic.php?t=140915).

I can create .csv waveforms and import them as .barb using the device (this is very slow).
When looking the contents of the created .barb in hex, I see for example:

```
0000000: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 f87f
0000010: cdcc 8c3f 9a99 993e 0000 80bf 0100 0000
0000020: 64b8 0b41 b415 ea40 0000 0000 0200 0000
0000030: 4c2f e540 00f9 1500 31ff ffff 0180 67e6
0000040: 67e6 67e6 67e6 67e6 67e6 67e6 0180 0180
0000050: 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180
0000060: 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180
0000070: 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180
0000080: 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 0180 6626
```

I recognize how the data are encoded, and I recognize the bytes that contain the number of samples (00f9 1500 = 144000 in the example).

So my question is where can I find how the header of the .barb files is encoded?

Comment: please post the actual text, not a screenshot of the text ... that way the data can be copied and searched on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some info and a script to generate them here: https://github.com/jeremyherbert/barbutils

Answer (score 0):

A quick search yielded this, it shows how to create a binary arb file in C#.

https://community.keysight.com/thread/20217

Comment: this doesn't show how to create one, only how to send one to the device

Comment: The key function is  oFio.WriteIEEEBlock from VISA

Comment: That’s not what the OP is asking unfortunately. That function is for writing binary data over a SCPI interface. BARB files are mainly stored on a USB drive which can be inserted into the instrument and selected using the front panel controls. It’s not the same as an IEEE block.

Comment: @jeremy this is exactly what I was looking for. But @LiorBilia 's link was very useful and it worked. With a C++ program, I connected with the VISA interface and invoked SCPI commands like (among others) `viPrintf(vi, "SOURce1:DATA:ARBitrary myARB, %*zb\n", NUM_DATA_POINTS, myVoltages);`. I didn't know the structure of the .barb file but I could do my job.